# How to update a value based on previous value in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am trying to update every current value based on the previous value of another property.

Actually, I need to do the task with dates, but just to keep it simple, I'll explain my problem with simple numbers.

I have

1. `Start`, which is `1`
2. `Stop`, which is already defined
3. `End`
4. `Duration`, which is already defined

My goal

- `Start` = `Duration` of previous index + `End` of previous index
- `End` = `Start` + `Stop` of current value

To illustrate, I added the screenshot of the table, how it should look like:

[image]

Current view:

[image]

Code below and [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-forked-islxp?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "./styles.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
function App() {
  let start = 1;
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = React.useState(null);
  const [gridColumnApi, setGridColumnApi] = React.useState(null);

  const onGridReady = (params) => {
    setGridApi(params.api);
    setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
  };

  const defaultColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    editable: true
  };

  const columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: "Name",
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      headerName: "start",
      field: "updatedStart"
    },
    { headerName: "stop", field: "stop" },
    {
      headerName: "end",
      field: "end"
    },
    {
      headerName: "duration",
      field: "duration",
      colId: "duration"
    }
  ];
  const rowData = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        name: "John",
        stop: 10,
        duration: 5
      },
      {
        name: "David",
        stop: 15,
        duration: 8
      },
      {
        name: "Dan",
        stop: 20,
        duration: 6
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const rowDataWithStart = React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
      rowData &&
      rowData.map((row, i) => ({
        ...row,
        start: start
      }))
    );
  }, [start, rowData]);

  const rowDataWitEnd = React.useMemo(() => {
    return (
      rowDataWithStart &&
      rowDataWithStart.map((row, i) => ({
        ...row,
        end: row.start + row.stop
      }))
    );
  }, [rowDataWithStart]);




//this function(rowDataWitUpdatedStart) should get the previous value of end and duration and get the total
  const rowDataWitUpdatedStart = React.useMemo(() => { 
    return (
      rowDataWitEnd &&
      rowDataWitEnd.map((row, i) => ({
        ...row,
        updatedStart: row.end + row.duration
      }))
    );
  }, [rowDataWitEnd]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 align="center">React-App</h1>
      <div className="ag-theme-alpine">
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          rowData={rowDataWitUpdatedStart}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          domLayout={"autoHeight"}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
        ></AgGridReact>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried to do the task making a use of `valueGetter` from the library I use: `AG Grid`, but seems to be not the best approach. See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71006528/how-to-increment-a-cell-in-ag-grid-react-tabel/71006835?noredirect=1#comment125525169_71006835)
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a step-wise transformation of your data, you can simply do all the operations you want in one go, using `Array.prototype.reduce`. The way we are going to use `Array.prototype.reduce` here is going to be almost similar to how you use `Array.prototype.map` (we are pushing the objects as-is into a new array, so there is no transformation of data), but the advantage is that we have access to the current index in the third argument, which allows us to access values of the previous item in the accumulator.

`Array.prototype.map` wouldn't work in this case because in each iteration it will not have access to the updated `start` in the previous item, unless you have a hack-ish way of storing it outside of the function.

With your logic, where you want `start` to be the duration + end of the previous item, we can use this logic:

```
curCopy.start = idx === 0 ? 1 : (acc[idx - 1].duration + acc[idx - 1].end);
```

...which basically says:

1. If we are on the first item, just start with the seed value of `1` for `start`
2. If not, then we access the previous entry (current index minus one) of the accumulator, and access its `duration` and `end` properties. Sum them up and use them for `start`

Use this logic in a new memoized array of objects returned:

```
const updatedRowData = React.useMemo(() => {
  const updated = rowData.reduce((acc, cur, idx) => {
    const curCopy =  {...cur};
    const previous = acc[idx - 1];
    curCopy.start = idx === 0 ? 1 : (previous.duration + previous.end);
    curCopy.end = curCopy.start + curCopy.stop;
    acc.push(curCopy);
    return acc;
  }, []);

  return updated;
}, [rowData]);
```

And then in your template, simply use `rowData={updatedRowData}`.
It should generate the results that you expected:

[image: Expected table results]

I have forked your sandbox to create a proof-of-concept example:

[image: Edit ag-grid (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through all elements, keeping a list of processed entries (result) and just add the start and end onto the item.

(Of course the first one is an anomaly as you need to hardcode the start to be at 1)

```
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
      const thisValue = rowData[i];
      if (i === 0) {
        const firstValue = { ...thisValue, start: 1, end: 1 + thisValue.stop };
        result.push(firstValue);
      } else {
        const previousValue = result[i - 1];
        const start = previousValue.end + previousValue.duration;
        const end = start + thisValue.stop;
        result.push({ ...thisValue, start, end });
      }
    }

    return result;
  }, [rowData]);
```

You can view this on my forked [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-forked-jv1ds?file=/src/App.js:1171-1728)